# Search for a specific value in JSON array

Tags: java

I have a JSON array that I am creating at my end and can be of variable length

```
String oktas =
    "{[{\"accountNumber\" : \"13176704\", \"paperless\" : \"true\", \"emailable\" : \"true\"},{\"accountNumber\" : \"13176704\", \"paperless\" : \"true\", \"emailable\" : \"true\"}]}";
```

After this I am doing one API call in which I need to check if the above account numbers are present or not. And if so, then I need to update the key values in my API call as per my JSON array.

My issue is I can iterate over the API call by converting it to list, but I don't want to create another loop to iterate my JSON array as well as it will increase the complexity. Is there any way  I can achieve that. Below is what I have tried, but is not working for me.

```
try {
    String oktas =
            "{{\"accountNumber\" : \"13176704\", \"paperless\" : \"true\", \"emailable\" : \"true\"},{\"accountNumber\" : \"13176704\", \"paperless\" : \"true\", \"emailable\" : \"true\"}}";
    List<Settings> Settings = getSettings(user);
    if (Settings != null && !Settings.isEmpty()) {
        for (Settings paperless : Settings) {
  // check if account number present in JSON array is present in API call
            if (oktas.contentEquals(paperless.getAccountNumber())) { 

               paperless.setPaperless(true); //set them based on my JSON array
               paperless.setEmailable(true);
               paperless.setUpdateFlag("B");
                

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
One simple way would be to convert the string to a JSON Array and then use it in anyway you like:


import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException
    {
         String oktas =
            "{{\"accountNumber\" : \"13176704\", \"paperless\" : \"true\", \"emailable\" : \"true\"},{\"accountNumber\" : \"13176704\", \"paperless\" : \"true\", \"emailable\" : \"true\"}}";
   
        JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(oktas);

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++)
        {
            JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);

            System.out.println(jsonObj);
        }

    }
}

Download java-json.jar from here, which contains org.json.JSONArray

http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/java/java-json.jar.zip

Unzip and add to your project's library: Project > Build Path > Configure build path> Select Library tab > Add External Libraries > Select the java-json.jar file.
```